# Create DrawerNavigator inside StackNavigator

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a bottomTabNavigator which looks like this.

`const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    [SCREEN1]: {
        screen: StackNavigator1
    },
    [SCREEN2]: {
        screen: StackNavigator2
    },
    [SCREEN3]: {
        screen: SplashScreen
    },
},`

Now, how I do I go about creating a DrawerNavigator on each of the screens ? Creating on a normal screen is fairly straightforward. How to create it within a stackNavigator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its pretty straight forward. You set the DrawerNavigator as the screen component. 
For example:

```
const dn1 = createDrawerNavigator({
   [Screen1]: {
       screen: Screen01
   }
});

const dn2= createDrawerNavigator({
    [Screen1]: {
        screen: Screen02
    }
 });

 const dn3 = createDrawerNavigator({
    [Screen1]: {
        screen: Screen03
    }
 });

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    [SCREEN1]: {
        screen: dn1
    },
    [SCREEN2]: {
        screen: dn2
    },
    [SCREEN3]: {
        screen: dn3
    },
}
```

This way you would have a separate DrawerNavigator for each tab.

Comment: I tried passing a StackNavigator inside my Drawer navigator and it throws errors ('The component for Screen01' must be React Component) 

and Screen01 is my StackNavigator

```const Screen01 = StackNavigator({ ... //some code })```

Comment: I tried your approach properly and it worked. Thanks